# Is it better to teach category theory in the background of type theory than set theory?

Tags: undergraduate-education, category-theory

I have been going over some applied instances of category theory in Programming, and also by a book by conceptual Mathematics by Lawvrere, and I think an issue of applying category theory to real life, is that there seems to be no point for quite a bit as all structures seem like sets, and it feels like we could just think of maybe functions than functors and so on.

A lot of the significance becomes much easier to process, I think, when we start thinking of objects in categories as types.

Is there anywhere I can find discussions on the pedagogic value of starting CT with types vs otherwise? Or could someone who is well versed with both approaches share their views on it?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that the vast majority of people in the US (possibly things are different in Europe) who are learning category theory are mathematicians with no significant computer science background and therefore don't know anything about types.  In part, this is a cultural issue within CS in the US because Engineering deans won't give tenure to people who don't have several million dollar grants and it's hard to get million dollar grants studying theoretical subjects such as category theory.

Comment: It's not uncommon for a mathematician to get their first serious exposure to category theory after learning the definition of a sheaf, and then the idea that a sheaf on a topological space X is a functor from the category of open sets of X (with arrows reversed) to the category of abelian groups is well-appreciated, whereas said mathematician still has no idea what a type is (having taken at most one or two introductory CS classes).

Comment: @AlexanderWoo To add weight to your point:  I was with you for sheaves and categories of open sets and abelian groups.  You lost me at "types".  But my phd is in fractal geometry, so what do I know?